# How does the stack work in multithreaded programs using Pthread?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, posix, thread-synchronization

I'm having a simple question, I believe, as far as I know, a multithreaded program, they share the process's memory space between all threads, that includes, stack, global memory area, file descriptors, etc., I I want to know why in the first example, there is a consistency problem, since theoretically all threads share the stack, in the second example, the race problem occurs.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void *thr(void *arg)
{
   for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
       printf("Thread = %zu Value= %d\n", pthread_self(), i);
   return NULL;
}

int main(void)
{
   pthread_t threads[2];
   for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
     pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, thr, NULL);
   for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
     pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
   return 0;
}
```

---

Second program with running problem

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

int i = 0;

void *thr(void *arg)
{
   for(; i < 50; i++)
     printf("Thread = %zu Value= %d\n", pthread_self(), i);
   return NULL;
}

int main(void)
{
   pthread_t threads[2];
   for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
     pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, thr, NULL);
   for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
     pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
   return 0;
}
```

---

3 example with race problem, in this case the variable is created in the main thread and is passed as argument to the function, that is, the only shared stack is from the main thread ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void *thr(void *arg)
{
   int *ptr = (int *)arg;
   for(; *ptr < 50; (*ptr)++)
     printf("Thread = %zu Value= %d\n", pthread_self(), *ptr);
   return NULL;
}

int main(void)
{
   int i = 0;
   pthread_t threads[2];
   for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
     pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, thr, &i);
   for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
     pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> share the process's memory space between all threads, that includes, stack

Well, yes and no.

There's a difference between sharing a <s>memory</s> address *space* and a specific region of memory.

While it is true that all threads share an address space, each thread has **its own stack** (allocation of memory).

A shared address space means that a given virtual address (pointer value) refers to the same physical memory in all threads.

But a dedicated stack means that each thread's stack pointer started off at a different place in that address space, so as to not conflict which each other.

Comment: Is the main thread stack shared? Because when I pass it as an argument, the other threads have access to it, but when I create a variable in another thread on the stack, it is not shared, that's what it seems to be

Comment: The stacks are all present in the same address space, but the regions within that space are separate.

Comment: @YuriBittencourt: All threads can access the stack of all other threads, because they are in the same [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space). For example, if one thread is passed a pointer to a variable on another thread's stack, it can access the variable without any restrictions (although possibly at a performance penalty, due to the way the [CPU cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache) works).

Comment: And why in the first example, the variable i, seems to n be visible to other threads, while in the third example, the variable i is visible to other threads?

Comment: @AndreasWenzel ?

Comment: This has nothing to do with address space, and everything to do with the undefined behavior you're invoking with the dangling pointer. Just don't pass a pointer to something on the stack to your child threads.

Comment: @YuriBittencourt: In the first example, you create two variables with the name `i`, one on the stack of the first worker thread and one on the stack of the second worker thread. Since they are only local variables and no pointer to these local variables is passed to any other thread, these variable are not accessible to the other threads. In the third example, however, you only create one variable with the name `i` on the stack of the main thread, but pass a pointer to that variable to both worker threads. That way, the variable is accessible from all threads.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: I don't see any dangling pointer. Which pointer in which example is dangling, in your opinion? The only undefined behavior I see is the race condition.

Comment: I think I understand, in this case all threads have their own stack in which they can be shared, but to be accessible a pointer must be passed to access the shared stack, in the second example, the variable i is being used in the section .bss or .data, as there is only one region, it is already accessible by all threads, correct? @AndreasWenzel

Comment: @YuriBittencourt: In which section it is stored or the number of regions is not important. What is more important is the number of variables that are created (two in the first example, one in the other examples), whether a pointer to these variables is passed to other threads, and the [scope](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/scope) of these variables.

Comment: @YuriBittencourt: In the second example, the variable `i` is accessible to the code of all threads, because it has file scope. In the third example, the variable `i` is not accessible directly, because it is out of scope. However, it is accessible indirectly through a pointer. In the first example, both variables with the name `i` of both threads are inaccessible to all other threads, because they are both out of scope and no pointer to these variables is being passed to other threads.

Comment: @YuriBittencourt: In your question, you are posting the code that you are using for your three examples, but you are not posting the results of your examples. Since your code has undefined behavior, the compiler may be optimizing the code in such a way that you are not getting the expected results. This could be confusing you and could be the reason why you are having trouble understanding what is going on. Therefore, you may want to write the results of your examples into your question, so we can provide further explanations.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel But if in the first example I use the local variable i with the static class, thus, static int i = 0, n would be accessible to other threads, wouldn't it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237071/discussion-between-andreas-wenzel-and-yuri-bittencourt).

Comment: @JonathonReinhart 'Just don't pass a pointer to something on the stack to your child threads' well, while if a specific case that might be bad, it's not bad practice in general, as long as the pointer target lifetime exceeds that of accesses from threads.

Comment: @MartinJames Yes, absolutely. Many programs will end with the main thread calling `pthread_join()` on all of the child threads, so the lifetime will always be valid. Writing on mobile, I just wasn't able to point out the subtleties of doing so.

Answer (score 3):

Every thread in a process has normally its own stack pointer (meaning it has its own stack).

This means that while they share the virtual address space, giving them access to other thread's variables or even the stack, they normally have their own stacks in different, non overlapping places of this shared virtual memory space.

When the kernel schedules a thread, it installs the thread's registers in the core or cpu it is going to use (and this includes the stack pointer with a value of stack for each thread)  Indeed, the kernel maintains a user mode stack for each thread **and also a kernel stack** (this last to allow two different threads of the same process to be executing a system call at the same time --the same or different--, which would not be possible if they had to share a single stack)

Comment: You're very wellcome! :)